# How do I average numbers according to each distinct ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have `CommentRating` table that holds a foreign key to the `DrinkId`. I'm trying to get the average ratings for each `DrinkId`, and along with that I want to display the top three drinkIds that have the highest ratings.

```
commentRating  drinkID 

     9           7

     9           4

     8          11

     8           7

     7           4

     6           4

     6          11
```

Here's the SQL I have so far, but I don't know how to change it.

```
Select TOP(3)(AVG(commentRating)),DISTINCT(drinkID)
FROM  Comment order by commentRating desc
```

How do I average the ratings, select the drinks with the top three ratings, and return them in SQL?

Comment: Please edit this to cleanly explain what you are trying to achieve. You mention Average but I don't see anywhere in your SQL where this has been attempted? 

What are you trying to do?

Comment: what platform are you using? mySQL or sql-server 2008?  Also, do you want the TOP 3 or the average by DrinkID?

Comment: Or indeed the average of the top 3?

Comment: @StuartAinsworth - I'd say SQL2008 from the use of the TOP keyword.

Comment: Tags says sql-server-2008 so it's t-sql!. @user1495988 why this has C# tag

Comment: Im using Visual Studio which is using C# for the sql with the sql server 2008

Comment: I've tried to improve your question and keep it from getting closed.  Some pointers: The title of your question should succicintly say *What* the problem is, not that you're having a problem. We know that, otherwise you wouldn't be here. Secondly, take care in punctuation and sentence format.  Even if English isn't your first language, having well formed sentences with appropriate capitalization and punctuation could be the difference between a question getting closed and staying open. Finally, make sure to show everything you've tried; people like to downvote questions that lack research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` the result by the `drinkID`:

```
SELECT TOP 3 AVG(commentRating), drinkID
FROM Comment
GROUP BY drinkID
ORDER BY AVG(commentRating) DESC
```

I recommend you to read your favorite SQL documentation about details on `GROUP BY`. For T-SQL it is [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177673.aspx).

`AVG` is an aggregate function. Again, I'd recommend you to read some documentation on aggregate functions, in T-SQL it's in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) too.

Answer (score 3):

For T-SQL:

```
select TOP 3 * from
(
select drinkID,avg(commentRating) avgCom 
from Comment group by drinkID
) t order by avgCom DESC
```

For MySQL use [LIMIT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) key word.